# How do I "Open the MainActivity class and add the corresponding method:"

Tags: android, class, android-activity, program-entry-point

I am trying to following the *Building Your First App* from the Android developers site, and I'm stuck on the Lesson: [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#RespondToButton/)

I downloaded and installed Eclipse SDK and the ADT plugin and that is what I am using.

I am hung up on the step on the page at the above link on the step where it says:

> Open the MainActivity class and add the corresponding method:
>
> ```
> /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
> public void sendMessage(View view) {
>     // Do something in response to button
> }
> ```
>
> Tip: In Eclipse, press Ctrl + Shift + O to import missing classes (Cmd + Shift + O on Mac).

I do not know what file I should open. I am using Windows, so I tried pressing CTRL + Shift + O and nothing happened. I tried looking for *.class files and could not find one. The only class file that I see is classes.dex and I don't think that is it. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck at? you should add that code to your activity class.

Comment: I do not know what or where the activity class is. Exactly where is the activity class? I have searched for help on this question and I can not find the answer. As I said, I am just starting today.

Comment: Am I looking for a file with an extension of .class? if so, I do not see one.

Comment: Well that is not a problem. I would recomend that you start with these video [tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3&feature=plcp). They really helped me when I was starting too. Good luck.

Comment: I think I found the answer. It is under /SRC/ProjectName/MainActivity.java

Comment: I found the answer in a post titled "How to define the main class in an Android App?" on this site. I appreciate the link to the video tutorials.

Comment: No problem, glad you are back on track :)

Answer (score 7):

I too had this problem and spent over an hour searching for the remedy. Which I found herewith:

Go to left navigation bar and go to /src/com.example/MainActivity.java

Double click MainActivity.Java

File opens up in main window, OK, before the last "}", insert your code

yellow lines appear (indicating some sort of error!)

to resolve this, hover the mouse over the yellow lines and you will see a popup. click the option that includes "import view".

You can now continue with the tutorial...

edit:typo

Comment: Awesome. Perfect answer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem:

in the package explorer the file is under src\com.example.my.first.app\MainActivity.java

the com.example.my.first.app is what i got there. if you named the project differently it should reflect that.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Look under the file heading `src` under `MyFirstApp` near the very top of the package explorer on the left side of the Eclipse screen.  Then look open the `com.example.MyFirstApp` folder and there it is.  Open it and start editing.

Answer (score 1):

stucked there too, but this answer helped alot. Don't forget to add "import android.view.View;" othwerwise you will get a "View cannot be resolveds to a type"-Message.

Answer (score 0):

**write this on button onclick()**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

**To pass info just use**

```
myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
```

**can be retrieved on the other side via**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

**Don't forget to add your new activity in the AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="NextActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you **checked every folder/package under /src/ in the Package Explorer** on the left side but you are sure there is none, this is what helped me continue the tutorial without starting over:
2. I got stuck there too, because the only MainActivity.java **file was at /gen/...  and not /src/...**, but I fixed it with deleting that exisiting one and creating a new one at /src/com.example.whatever/. Just New > Class, Name MainActivity and paste the following code:

   ```
   package com.example.androidtest;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.Menu;    

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {    

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
           return true;
       }

   }
   ```

   ..and now you have your MainActivity.java and can go on! (You can create a new Android Project and copy&paste the MainActivity to your existing project. You just have to adjust the )
3. **In case this didn't help** it might be, that **you never had a MainActivity class** in the first place. To fix this, click on New > Android > Android Activity, choose Blank Activity and enter MainActivity as name in the next panel. I tried this first but got an error, that the layout name "activity_main" already exists.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm coding in Flutter in Android Studio.
I found the file MainActivity.java with double shift key. The path is:

**android\app\src\main\kotlin\com.example\MainActivity**